# close marker infowindow and change marker color on click

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Hello I've tried a lot of the samples on stackoverflow not sure where I'm going wrong. I have a map with some markers there work fine (change color and open infowindow the problem is I want the previous marker to change back to original color close infowindow when a new marker is selected. Not sure where I'm going wrong.

```
<script type="text/javascript">             
        $(document).ready(function(){
            var i=0;
            var currentInfoWin = null;
            var currentMarker = null;
            var mapOptions = {
                mapTypeId:google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
            };
            var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),mapOptions);
            $.getJSON('map.php',function(data){
                if(data.success == true) {
                    if(data.CData.length > 0){
                        $.each(data.CData,function(index, d){
                        addMarker(currentMarker, currentInfoWin, map, d.Latitude, d.Longitude);
                        });
                    }
                }           
            });     
        });

        function addMarker(currentMarker, currentInfoWin, map, Active, Lat, Lng){
            if (Lat != null && Lng != null){
                var LatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(Lat, Lng);                                      
                var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: LatLng,
                    map: map,
                    icon:{
                        path: google.maps.SymbolPath.CIRCLE,
                        scale: 5.0,
                        fillColor: "#F00",
                        fillOpacity: 0.7,
                        strokeWeight: 0.4
                    },
                });

                var content = '<div class="">test</div>';

                var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({ 
                    content: content,
                    maxWidth: 370
                });

                google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function (){
                    resetInfoWindow(currentInfoWin,currentMarker);
                    marker.setIcon({
                        path: google.maps.SymbolPath.CIRCLE,
                        scale: 5,
                        fillColor: "#00F",
                        fillOpacity: 0.7,
                        strokeWeight: 0.4
                    });
                    infowindow.open(map, marker);
                    currentInfoWin = infowindow;
                    currentMarker = marker;
                });             
            }               
        }

        function resetInfoWindow(currentInfoWin,currentMarker){
            if(currentInfoWin!==null){
                currentInfoWin.close();
                currentMarker.setIcon({
                    path: google.maps.SymbolPath.CIRCLE,
                    scale: 5,
                    fillColor: "#F00",
                    fillOpacity: 0.7,
                    strokeWeight: 0.4
                });
            }
        }

    </script>
```

Comment: Can you provide sample data?  Or better yet, a [Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates your issue.

Comment: Hi geocodezip; 

Thank you for replying sorry about all the code I cleaned it up as much as I think I could/should. Basically it goes through a loop reading a JSON file and then calls addmarker function each time. This puts the marker on the map. 

In the add marker I also call the click listener which opens the infowindow. before that it calls the resetinfowindow to check if there was a window open closes it and then goes back to open the new one.

Comment: The problem is it's "working" on the same marker.  Thus if I click on marker A it opens if I click on Marker B it opens. If I click on marker A again it closes and opens back.....

So I can't figure out how to save the last marker clicked reset it and open just the new one. I think I have to create and Array of the Markers and call the addlistener seperately? outside the loop? I seem to have a mental block on this one.

Thanks again!

Comment: Sounds like a problem that can be solved by function closure.  You still didn't provide sample data or a [Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 2):

So I figured it out: I put the markers and infowindows in an array used a loop on click to reset all markers before opening and setting new marker... also removed the resetInfoWindow function. Not sure if this is the most efficient way there is please chime in. Thanks again!

```
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function (){
    for (var i = 0; i < MarkerArray.length; i++) {
         MarkerArray[i].setIcon({
             path: google.maps.SymbolPath.CIRCLE,
             scale: 5,
             fillColor: "#F00",
             fillOpacity: 0.7,
             strokeWeight: 0.4
         });
      InfoWindowArray[i].close();
    }
    marker.setIcon({
        path: google.maps.SymbolPath.CIRCLE,
        scale: 5,
        fillColor: "#00F",
        fillOpacity: 0.7,
        strokeWeight: 0.4
    });
    infowindow.open(map, marker);
});
```